# Confusion in by default chunk size in GridFS

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongo-java

MongoDB manual says [by default chunk size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs) is 255K.

Its current Java API says [its](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html) 256K.

Which one is right or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be 256K, and has since been changed to 255K. The extra 1K is for meta-data overhead, while still being within 256K.

This has been fixed in 2.12.0 and 3.0.0: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1154

This appears to be an error in the documentation. The JIRA ticket references git commits that fix it in the code. Feel free to open up a documentation-related ticket within the [MongoDB Java Driver Project JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA/).